# Random number generator not working with the sumproduct function

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I would like to write a single formula that is able to calculate "n" randomly generated figures, as well as average them, where n is determined by a changing reference cell.

The current formula I am using is this:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT((ROW(1:6)*RAND()/ROW(1:6))/6
```

However, the random number is only generated once and is being used in all 6 terms. Note in this case my n=6, hence I would like six randomly generated numbers being created inside the formula.

I used the following function to establish if only one random number was being generated:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT((ROW(1:6)*(IF(RAND()<1-0,3;(1-0,3);0,3))/ROW(1:6))/6
```

The final product would always be 0,3 or 0,7 and therefore confirming the fact

Comment: Do you want the 6 random numbers listed inside the single cell you enter this formula in?

Comment: You can try RANDBETWEEN instead with a tiny fraction variation in the upper limit

Comment: Hi Kyle, I want the average of 6 random numbers in the single cell.

Comment: Hi Slai, thanks, I'll look into your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correct.
You want to generate "n" different random numbers and then want to take average of these numbers. This will be ultimately a single random number as it's average of 6 different random numbers.

Let me know if it helps or you need to do some calculation with all these random number so we can suggest you an alternative.